# Why low-pass smoothing of a closed 2D curve conserves its area?

Tags: calculus, geometry, fourier-analysis

Consider a practical example where the 2D curve—could be a sequence of points—denotes the measured border of a certain water body. The measurement contains random noise and must be smoothed for certain use (for example, hydrodynamic simulation). We don’t want the area to be affected by the smoothing. The question is—which smoothing method should be used?

Below is an example of low-pass smoothing, the area does appear to be conserved.
[image: Example low-pass smoothing, the area appears to be conserved]

I read from this old 1995 paper [https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs468-01-fall/Papers/taubin-smoothing.pdf] which states "the method of Fourier descriptors does not produce shrinkage...", but couldn’t figure out why.

I know that with proper parameterization, the coordinates of a closed curve (in any dimension, including 2D) could be considered as a $2π$-periodic function. For example, we have $(a \cos ⁡t,b \sin ⁡t )$ for an ellipse. I also know that the area enclosed by a 2D curve $(x(t),y(t))$ could be found via Green's formula
$$A={1 \over 2} \oint_0^{2\pi} x y'-x' y \, \mathrm{d}t.$$
But it seems the area formula could not be analyzed in the Fourier space, so I post the question here expecting some Fourier guru to help out. Thanks!

Comment: Try using a polar coordinate system with the origin anywhere inside the closed curve. If you have a polygon with $N$ vertices, $( x_i , y_i )$, $1 \le i \le N$, and a point $( x_0 , y_0 )$ inside the polygon, then $r_i = \sqrt{(x_i - x_0)^2 + (y_i - y_0)^2}$ and $\varphi_i = \operatorname{atan2}\left((y_i-y_0), (x_i-x_0)\right)$, where $\operatorname{atan2}(y, x)$ is a version of $\operatorname{atan}(y / x)$ that includes the quadrant (depending on signs of $x$ and $y$).

Comment: @NominalAnimal I don't think casting the problem into polar coordinates leads to any progress.

Comment: Consider a polygon with $N$ edges. In polar coordinates, it decomposes into $N$ triangles, each with signed area $$A_i = \frac{1}{2} r_i r_{i+1} \sin(\varphi_{i+1} - \varphi_i)$$with the total area being $$A = \sum_{i=1}^N A_i$$This means that any manipulation of $r_i$ that keeps all products $r_i r_{i+1}$ (including $A_N = \frac{1}{2} r_N r_1 \sin(\varphi_1 - \varphi_N)$) unchanged, keeps the polygon area unchanged.